# Is there a "universal" connected compact metric space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

**Fact 1.** The Cantor set $K$ is "universal" among nonempty compact metric spaces in the following sense: given any nonempty compact metric space $X$, there exists a continuous surjection $f\colon K \to X$.

**Fact 2.** The closed interval $I$ has a similar "universal" property among nonempty compact connected and locally connected metric spaces: given any such space $X$, there exists a continuous surjection $f \colon I \to X$.

This makes me wonder: **is there a compact connected metric space $J$ such that for any nonempty compact connected metric space $X$, there exists a continuous surjection $f \colon J \to X$?**

Such a space $J$, if it exists, would be 'intermediate' between $I$ and $K$: there would need to be continuous surjections

$$    K \to J \to I $$

Fact 1 is sometimes called the **Alexandroff–Hausdorff theorem**, since appeared in the second edition of Felix Hausdorff’s *Mengenlehre* in 1927 and also in an article by Pavel Alexandroff published in *Mathematischen Annalen* in the same year.  Fact 2 was proved by Hans Hahn in 1914 and reproved by him more nicely in 1928.   For a nice history of these results, see:

- L. Koudela, [The Hausdorff–Alexandroff theorem and its application in theory of curves](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.8605&rep=rep1&type=pdf), *WDS'07 Proceedings of Contributed Papers*, Part I, 2007, pp. 257–260.

One may rightly complain that "universal" is the wrong word above, since we're *not* claiming there exists a *unique* continuous surjection, and indeed there's usually not.  A better term is **versal**.  There can be two non-homeomorphic spaces having the same versal property.  For example, $I^2$ would work just as well as $I$ in Fact 2, thanks to the existence of space-filling curves.

Nonetheless we can create a category in which these versal properties become universal, by a cheap trick.  Let $\mathrm{CompMet}$ be the collection of all homeomorphism classes of nonempty compact metric spaces, and put a partial order on this where $[X] \ge [Y]$ iff there exists a continuous surjection $f \colon X \to Y$.   The homeomorphism class of the Cantor set is the top element of the poset $\mathrm{CompMet}$.  My question asks if the subset of $\mathrm{CompMet}$ coming from connected compact metric spaces has a top element.

I'd also appreciate any interesting information on this poset $\mathrm{CompMet}$.

For example, I think that there's a map sending each element of $\mathrm{CompNet}$ to its number of connected components, and I think that this is an order-preserving map from $\mathrm{CompMet}$ to the cardinals less than or equal to the continuum.  But there also seems to be an order-preserving map sending each element of $\mathrm{CompNet}$ to its number of path-connected components.  Are there other interesting maps like this?

Comment: This is nit-picky, but wouldn't it be more appropriate to call these universal metrizable spaces, rather than metric spaces? Since we are asking for existence of continuous maps, not isometries, and as a result there is no preferred metric to choose on $K$ or $I$, just any that is compatible with the topology

Comment: Yes, we can say "metrizable".

Comment: Another versal property: the [pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) maps onto every **chainable** continuum, meaning one for which every open cover refines to a cover $U_1, \dots , U_n$ where $U_i \cap U_j \ne \emptyset$ iff $|i - j| \le 1$.   This was [proved by Mioduszewski in 1962](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/51/2/95052/a-functional-conception-of-snake-like-continua).

Comment: At least, so say [Irwin and Solewecki](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-07/S0002-9947-06-03928-6/).  But looking at Mioduszewski's paper linked to above, I see he claims that pseudo-arc maps onto every 'snake-like' continuum.  He doesn't define this concept, but elsewhere I read that a continuum is snake-like if it's chainable and has an extra property too.  So, I don't get why Irwin and Solewecki claim what they do.

Comment: "chainable," "linearly chainable," and "snake-like" are often used to mean the same thing.

Comment: Okay, good - I see [this encyclopedia](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Snake-like_continuum) defines snake-like to mean the same thing as what I'd call chainable.  The pseudo-arc is chainable but also what Wikipedia calls "[crooked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc)", and I mistakenly assumed snake-like was a synonym for crooked.

Answer (score 37):

There is no such continuum. See

Z. Waraszkiewicz, *[Sur un problème de M.H. Hahn](https://eudml.org/doc/212685)*, Fund. Math. 22 (1934) 180–205.

Waraszkiewicz constructed an uncountable family $W$ of continua in the plane called Waraszkiewicz spirals so that no continuum can be mapped continuously onto every continuum in $W$. Start with the space $X=S^1\cup [1,2]$ and consider the maps $f,g:X\to X$ where

- $f(x)=x$ if $x\in S^1$, $f(x)=\exp(4\pi ix)$ for $1\leq x\leq \frac{3}{2}$, and $f(x)=2(x-1)$ for $\frac{3}{2}\leq x\leq 2$
- $g(x)=x$ if $x\in S^1$, $g(x)=\exp(-4\pi ix)$ for $1\leq x\leq \frac{3}{2}$, and $g(x)=2(x-1)$ for $\frac{3}{2}\leq x\leq 2$

Now $W$ is the collection of all inverse limits of all inverse sequences $(X_i,h_i)$ where $X_i=X$ for all $i$ and $h_i\in\{f,g\}$.

For a short and readable description (where I found the construction) see:

W.T. Ingram, *[Concerning images of continua](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v16/tp16010.pdf)*, Topology Proceedings 16 (1991) 89-93.

This non-existence results has been improved upon a few times, for instance in the following:

S.B. Nadler, *[The nonexistence of almost continuous surjections between certain continua](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2005.01.042)*, Topology and its Applications, 154 (2007) 1008-1014.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a related positive result:

Alan Dow and KP Hart proved in 1998 that the (non-metrizable) continuum $\beta[0,1)\setminus [0,1)$ maps onto every continuum of weight $\leq \omega_1$, and therefore onto every metrizable continuum. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9805008.pdf.

Comment: What's the "weight" of a continuum?

Comment: minimum cardinality of a basis